# DAG failure during the initial run

Tags: airflow

I have two DAGs:

DAG_A , DAG_B.

DAG_A triggers DAG_B thru TriggerDagRunOperator.

My tasks in DAG_B:

```
with DAG(
        dag_id='DAG_B',
        default_args=default_args,
        schedule_interval='@once',
        description='ETL pipeline for processing users'
) as dag:
    
    start = DummyOperator(
        task_id='start')
        
    delete_xcom_task = PostgresOperator(
      task_id='clean_up_xcom',
      postgres_conn_id='postgres_default',
      sql="delete from xcom where dag_id='DAG_A' and  task_id='TASK_A' ")
           
    end = DummyOperator(
        task_id='end')
        #trigger_rule='none_failed')
    
    #num_table is set by DAG_A. Will have an empty list initially.
    iterable_string = Variable.get("num_table",default_var="[]")
    iterable_list = ast.literal_eval(iterable_string) 

    for index,table in enumerate(iterable_list):
        table = table.strip()
        
        read_src1 = PythonOperator(
        task_id=f'Read_Source_data_{table}',
        python_callable=read_src,
        op_kwargs={'index': index}
        )
        upload_file_to_directory_bulk1 = PythonOperator(
        task_id=f'ADLS_Loading_{table}',
        python_callable=upload_file_to_directory_bulk,
        op_kwargs={'index': index}
        )
        write_Snowflake1 = PythonOperator(
        task_id=f'Snowflake_Staging_{table}',
        python_callable=write_Snowflake,
        op_kwargs={'index': index}
        )
        task_sf_storedproc1 = DummyOperator(
         task_id=f'Snowflake_Processing_{table}'
        )
        
        start >>  read_src1 >> upload_file_to_directory_bulk1 >> write_Snowflake1 >>task_sf_storedproc1  >> delete_xcom_task >> end
```

After executing `airflow db init`  and making the webserver and scheduler up, DAG_B fails with failure in task delete_xcom_task.

```
2021-06-22 08:04:43,647] {taskinstance.py:871} INFO - Dependencies not met for <TaskInstance: Target_DIF.clean_up_xcom 2021-06-22T08:04:27.861718+00:00 [queued]>, dependency 'Trigger Rule' FAILED: Task's trigger rule 'all_success' requires all upstream tasks to have succeeded, but found 2 non-success(es). upstream_tasks_state={'total': 2, 'successes': 0, 'skipped': 0, 'failed': 0, 'upstream_failed': 0, 'done': 0}, upstream_task_ids={'Snowflake_Processing_products', 'Snowflake_Processing_inventories'}
[2021-06-22 08:04:43,651] {local_task_job.py:93} INFO - Task is not able to be run
```

But both DAGs become successful from the second runs.

Can anyone explain me what is happening internally?

How can I avoid the failure during the first run?

Thanks.

Comment: What is the state and the log output of the 'Snowflake_Processing_products', 'Snowflake_Processing_inventories' tasks?

Comment: Failed state.
[2021-06-22 10:29:38,243] {taskinstance.py:871} INFO - Dependencies not met for <TaskInstance: Target_DIF.clean_up_xcom 2021-06-22T10:29:33.930725+00:00 [queued]>, dependency 'Trigger Rule' FAILED: Task's trigger rule 'all_success' requires all upstream tasks to have succeeded, but found 2 non-success(es). upstream_tasks_state={'total': 2, 'successes': 0, 'skipped': 0, 'failed': 0, 'upstream_failed': 0, 'done': 0}, upstream_task_ids={'Snowflake_Processing_inventories', 'Snowflake_Processing_products'}

Comment: This is the log output that you get on the console. But I mean the log output of those tasks themselves.

Comment: @SergiyKolesnikov Contents of both are same.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that the problem is in `schedule_interval='@once'` for `DAG_B`: When you add the DAG for the first time, the `schedule_interval` tells the scheduler to run the DAG once. So, `DAG_B` is triggered once by the scheduler and not by `DAG_A`. Any preparations that needs to be done by `DAG_A` for `DAG_B` to run successfully have not been done yet, therefore `DAG_B` fails.

Later on, `DAG_A` runs as scheduled and triggers `DAG_B` as expected. Both succeed.

To avoid `DAG_B` being triggered by the scheduler set `schedule_interval=None`.

Comment: Facing the same issue even after updating the DAG_B with schedule_interval=None